# rock paper scissors python. while loop not working

Tags: python

the code is clean but the while loop keeps looping the if statement when I want it to loop the whole thing over again ex.

```
Rock paper or scissors \\print statement\\
rock \\user input\\
\\keeps relooping same thing\\
oponent chose rock aswell
oponent chose rock aswell
oponent chose rock aswell
oponent chose rock aswell
```

here's the code

```
import random

follow_up=random.randint(1,3)
choice=input("Rock paper or scissors\n").lower()

  while True:
    if choice=="rock":
       if follow_up==1:
           print("oponent chose rock aswell")
        
       elif follow_up==2:
           print("oponent chose paper. you lose")
       elif follow_up==3:
           print("oponent chose sissors. you win")
       else:
           break
    
    
   if  choice=="paper":
        if follow_up==1:
            print("oponent chose rock. you win")
        elif follow_up==2:
            print("oponent chose paper aswell")
        elif follow_up==3:
            print("oponent chose sissors. you lose")
        else:
            break
        
    if  choice=="scissors":
        if follow_up==1:
            print("oponent chose rock. you lose")
        elif follow_up==2:
            print("oponent chose paper. you win")
        elif follow_up==3:
            print("oponent chose sissors asswell")
            else:
            break
```

Comment: This is a good moment to use a debugger and step through your code and inspect variables as you do. You'll soon find out where it goes wrong. Check for instance how many times `input` is executed and what that means for the user...

Comment: Two lines of your code are outside the loop, so they won't repeat. Which ones do you think it is?

Comment: enzo can u just give me a free-b and give me some functioning source code